# how to sort a mongoDB collection based on mapped value

Tags: mongodb

a simple question (hopefully) to mongoDB users
i have 2 collection
collection A have a data with ID which the name (describing the ID) located in collection B.
i would like to query mongo to get all the Items from Collection A sorted ASC by the mapped name from Collection B.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

well,
i found a simple solution for it:

```
db.createCollection("ColA")
db.createCollection("ColB")

db.ColA.insert({name:"Item1",priorityid:1})
db.ColA.insert({name:"Item2",priorityid:2})
db.ColA.insert({name:"Item3",priorityid:3})
db.ColA.insert({name:"Item4",priorityid:1})
db.ColA.insert({name:"Item5",priorityid:2})
```

ColA:

```
{"_id":"5fd7c79f774870001fa36872","name":"Item1","priorityid":1}
{"_id":"5fd7c7a9774870001fa36873","name":"Item2","priorityid":2}
{"_id":"5fd7c7bb774870001fa36875","name":"Item3","priorityid":3}
{"_id":"5fd7c7c8774870001fa36876","name":"Item4","priorityid":1}
{"_id":"5fd7c7d5774870001fa36877","name":"Item5","priorityid":2}

db.ColB.insert({name:"b_high",priorityid:1})
db.ColB.insert({name:"a_medium",priorityid:2})
db.ColB.insert({name:"c_low",priorityid:3})
```

ColB:

```
{"_id":"5fd7c810774870001fa3687b","name":"b_high","priorityid":1}
{"_id":"5fd7c842774870001fa3687c","name":"a_medium","priorityid":2}
{"_id":"5fd7c851774870001fa3687d","name":"c_low","priorityid":3}
```

Query:

```
db.ColA.aggregate([
{
  $lookup:
   {
     from: "ColB",
     localField: "priorityid",
     foreignField: "priorityid",
     as: "priorityname"
   }
  },   {   $unwind:"$priorityname" }, {   
    $project:{
        _id : 1,
        name : 1,
        priorityname : "$priorityname.name"
    } 
   },{ $sort : { priorityname : 1 } }
   ])
```

result:

```
{"_id":"5fd7c7a9774870001fa36873","name":"Item2","priorityname":"a_medium"}
{"_id":"5fd7c7d5774870001fa36877","name":"Item5","priorityname":"a_medium"}
{"_id":"5fd7c79f774870001fa36872","name":"Item1","priorityname":"b_high"}
{"_id":"5fd7c7c8774870001fa36876","name":"Item4","priorityname":"b_high"}
{"_id":"5fd7c7bb774870001fa36875","name":"Item3","priorityname":"c_low"}
```